# what is the wrong of this regex pattern for nested {* *}?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pattern-matching

I have this HTML document

```
{*
<h2 class="block_title bg0">ahmooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooodi</h2>
<div class="block_content padding bg0">{welc_msg}</div>
<br/>
    {*
    hii<br /><span>5
    *}

    {*
    hii<br /><span>5

    *}
*}
```

I want to remove it, so I want to remove anything between `{* *}`

I wrote regex pattern:

```
preg_replace("#(\{\*(.*?)\*\})+#isx",'',$html);
```

and it works, but it doesn't work ideally 100%, it's leaving `*}` at the end.

Can you give me the true pattern?

Comment: You need to use a [recursive regex](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) to match nested structures?

Comment: how please ? i didn't wrote recursive regex before

Comment: Your languages of nested patterns is not [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Thus you can’t use (normal) regular expressions. But [PCRE supports recursive patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) that you can use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex engine supports matching nested structures, (and PHP does), then you can remove the (possibly nested) elements in one pass like so:

### Recursive regex applied with one pass:

```php
function stripNestedElementsRecursive($text) {
    return preg_replace('/
        # Match outermost (nestable) "{*...*}" element.
        \{\*        # Element start tag sequence.
        (?:         # Group zero or more element contents alternatives.
          [^{*]++   # Either one or more non-start-of-tag chars.
        | \{(?!\*)  # or "{" that is not beginning of a start tag.
        | \*(?!\})  # or "*" that is not beginning of an end tag.
        | (?R)      # or a valid nested matching tag element.
        )*          # Zero or more element contents alternatives.
        \*\}        # Element end tag sequence.
        /x', '', $text);
}
```

The above recursive regex matches the *outermost* `{*...*}` element, which may contain nested elements.

However, if your regex engine does not support matching nested structures, you can still get the job done, but you cannot do it in one pass. A regex can be crafted that matches an *innermost*  `{*...*}` element, (i.e. one that does NOT contain any nested elements). This regex can be applied in a recursive manner until there are no more elements in the text like so:

### Non-recursive regex applied recursively:

```php
function stripNestedElementsNonRecursive($text) {
    $re = '/
        # Match innermost (not nested) "{*...*}" element.
        \{\*        # Element start tag sequence.
        (?:         # Group zero or more element contents alternatives.
          [^{*]++   # Either one or more non-start-of-tag chars.
        | \{(?!\*)  # or "{" that is not beginning of a start tag.
        | \*(?!\})  # or "*" that is not beginning of an end tag.
        )*          # Zero or more element contents alternatives.
        \*\}        # Element end tag sequence.
        /x';
    while (preg_match($re, $text)) {
        $text = preg_replace($re, '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Dealing with nested structures with regex is an advanced topic and one must *tread carefully!* If one really wants to use regex for advanced applications such as this, I would highly recommend reading the classic work on this subject: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) By Jeffrey Friedl. I can honestly say that this is the most useful book that I have ever read.

Happy Regexing!

Answer (score 1):

You need a [recursive regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) to match the nested parenthesis. It should look like this:

```
"#(\{\*([^{}]*?(?R)[^{}]*?)\*\})+#isx"
```

Comment: Close, but `\{\*([^{}]*?(?R)[^{}]*?)\*\}` fails to match if element contains an isolated `{` e.g. "`{* won't match {these} contents *}`".

Comment: @ridgerunner: Right, I completely overlooked that the delimiter consists of two chars :-/ Instead of fixing it (and making the regex even more unreadable than it already is), I'll just upvote your answer!